# Use of unresolved identifier 'Album' error - when trying to add a push pin to a MKMapView(IOS) when touching

Tags: ios, swift

```
let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MapViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)
```

Handling the gesture:

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer){
if gestureRecognizer.state != .began { return }

let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
let touchMapCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

let album = Album(coordinate: touchMapCoordinate, context: sharedContext)

mapView.addAnnotation(album)
```

}

I get

> error Use of unresolved identifier 'Album'

[image]

Comment: what's Album attach it

Comment: What is album?? and how it is added to your project?

Comment: actually this is my question ? I guess it could be a deprecated method to create list of "touchMapCoordinate" for "addAnnotation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off course it isn't , it would be

```
class Album: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?


    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String {

        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Then use

```
let album = Album(coordinate:touchMapCoordinate, title: "myTitle", subtitle: "mySub") 
mapView.addAnnotation(album)
```

And implement

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { }
```